# Help manipulating vectors/matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

Hello I have a rather specific question.

I am trying to follow a derivation and can't work out the last step.
Given:
$$s\,X(s) = (A-B\,K\,C) X(s) + B\,K\,V(s)$$ 
and
$$Y(s) = CX(s)$$

Multiplying $Y(s) = CX(s)$ through by s, then substituting in $sX(s)$....

Here is where I am at:
$$
sY(s) = C{((A-BKC)X(s) + BKV(s))}
$$

A is an n x n matrix, K is 1 x n, X(s) is n x 1.

However, the final form is given as this:
$$
Y(s) = C(sI-A+BKC)^{-1}BK V(s)
$$

Hoping someone can help me with the intermediate steps.

Comment: Is $V$ also an $n\times1$ matrix?

Comment: Yes I think so, or maybe a 1x1...

Comment: I think maybe Y and V are 1x1

Comment: Could it be that the first equation actually should be: $s\,X(s) = (A-B\,K\,C) X(s) + B\,K\,V(s)$ and $Y(s)=C\,X(s)$?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, you are absolutely right. I have perhaps tried to jump a step here. Yes, you are absolutely correct.

Comment: I was thinking to multiply $$Y(s) = CX(s)$$ by s and then substitute for $$sX(s)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the equation expressed in $X(s)$ and $V(s)$ and solving it for $X(s)$ yields,

$$
s\, X(s) - \left(A - B\, K\, C\right) X(s) = \left(s\, I - A + B\, K\, C\right) X(s) = B\, K\, V(s),
$$

$$
X(s) = \left(s\, I - A + B\, K\, C\right)^{-1} B\, K\, V(s).
$$

Now using the definition of $Y(s)$ yields,

$$
Y(s) = C\, X(s) = C \left(s\, I - A + B\, K\, C\right)^{-1} B\, K\, V(s).
$$